# Tool for advanced lossy JPEG optimization

Tags: image-processing, optimization, jpeg2000

#### Short question

I need to optimize my JPEG pictures targeted for the web. So I'm looking for a tool that achieves maximum compression while retaining an optimum of the quality. Choosing a default quality of 80 doesn't seem optimal.

#### Some background

Though I've read about a lot of tools available for the purpose, I'm confused in defining what tool(s) I should choose for jpeg optimizations targeted for the web. I already found:

- cjpeg from mozjpeg (most trendy)
- jpegoptim (old but recommended before)
- jpegrescan (don't know it much)
- adept-jpg-compressor (processes different part of the images with different quality)

Which tool would you recommend (not necessarily from those I've listed) and why?

Comment: Sorry, but this question appears to be about software comparisons which is off-topic at software recommendations. If you rewrote your question asking for software that meets certain requirements, that then would be on-topic.

Comment: As @Tom already pointed out, please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) I've rephrased your question to prevent it from being closed, and hope I've met your intentions. Please [edit] it again and add missing details: What OS must the tool run on? What is your price limit? Must the tool allow for commercial use?

Comment: Can I tag onto this that its unclear as to whether this is meant to be open source or commercial, as there are some very specialised tools that do just that.